# Use of \$ at end of variable name passed to grep

Tags: shell, shell-script, grep, regular-expression

I was going through one of the shell scripts and found a line:

```
ls $dir | grep -c "$NAME.${var}\$"
```

I understand that `$` would expand the variables `NAME` and `var`, but is it required to put `\$` at the end?

Answer (score 2):

`grep` uses the string `"$NAME.${var}\$"` as a regular expression. Presumably, before your troubling line of code, shell variables `name` and `var` had values assigned, so that the shell interpreting your script values for `$NAME` and `${var}`. Since the final "$" of the regular expression is escaped with a backslash, the shell interpreting your script does not try to interpolate a shell variable's value. The "$" gets passed to `grep` as part of the regular expression. And indeed, "$" has special meaning to `grep` in the context of a regular expression. "$" means "end of line" to `grep`. Nothing but the semantics of what you `grep` for demands the final "$".

Answer (score 0):

So here are the findings:
Suppose I create files in a directory, say named : john, alex_john, alex_john1 and john1 and I perform following:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls | grep "john"
john
alex_john
alex_john1
john1
[root@localhost ~]# ls | grep "john\$"   <==here it would insert end of line
john
alex_john
[root@localhost ~]#
```

So for the second grep only the files ending with john will be printed.